# Remove datePublished and dateModified from Yoast SEO plugin generated Article schema

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I'm trying to remove date properties from Article schema generated by the Yoast SEO plugin.

In their developer [docs](https://developer.yoast.com/features/schema/api/#change-a-graph-pieces-data) the `wpseo_schema_article` filter is set as an example for manipulating with Article graph piece. However even with this `type="application/ld+json"`:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
   "@context":"https://schema.org",
   "@type":"Article",
   "mainEntityOfPage":{
      "@type":"WebPage",
      "@id":"https://www.myproscooter.com/etwow-electric-scooters-review/"
   },
   "headline":"E-Twow Electric Scooters 2021 Review",
   "image":{
      "@type":"ImageObject",
      "url":"https://www.myproscooter.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/elek-scoot.jpg",
      "width":700,
      "height":400
   },
   "datePublished":"2020-12-08T08:52:13",
   "dateModified":"2021-01-12T11:30:10",
   "author":{
      "@type":"Person",
      "name":"Jason"
   },
   "publisher":{
      "@type":"Organization",
      "name":"MyProScooter",
      "logo":{
         "@type":"ImageObject",
         "url":"https://www.myproscooter.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/MPS-Logo-228x60.png"
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

When I try to access and manipulate data like this:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_schema_article', 'remove_article_dates' );


function remove_article_dates( $data ) {

    file_put_contents(WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/helper-seo.txt','DATA PRE FILTER: '.print_r($data,true),FILE_APPEND);

    unset($data['datePublished']);
    unset($data['dateModified']);

    return $data;
}
```

Nothing gets logged into helper-seo.txt nor do dates get unset in the Article schema; as if the filter is ignored totally.

What's more confusing is that manipulation with dates in Webpage Schema works and is similar to the above:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_schema_webpage', 'remove_webpage_dates');

function remove_webpage_dates( $data ) {

    unset($data['datePublished']);
    unset($data['dateModified']);

    return $data;
}
```

The other stuff I've tried include:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_schema_article_date_published', '__return_false' );

add_filter( 'wpseo_schema_article_date_modified', '__return_false' );
```

Which isn't reflecting into Article schema at all. **How to remove these properties sucessfully?**

Answer (score 1):

None of those solutions worked for me, and I finally had to modify the Yoast plugin file \wordpress-seo\src\presenters\open-graph\article-modified-time-presenter.php and change line 32 `return $this->presentation->open_graph_article_modified_time;` to this instead `return null;` and yes I realize that'll get overwritten by future plugin updates.

Comment: their documentation and support sucks, stuck with this too. Even tried with string  \Yoast\WP\SEO\Generators\Schema\Article\datePublished; which is literally their doc step by step, nothing.

Comment: found a way, check my reply below

Answer (score 0):

i am using this code, it will work

```
add_filter ( 'wpseo_schema_webpage' , 'remove_breadcrumbs_property_from_webpage' , 11 , 1 ) ;
function remove_breadcrumbs_property_from_webpage( $data ) {
    if (array_key_exists('datePublished', $data)) {
        unset($data['datePublished']);
        unset($data['dateModified']);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this exact code. I'm sure it will work for you. This cleared my problems at least.

```html
// Remove DatePublished
add_filter( 'wpseo_schema_graph_pieces', 'remove_datePublished_from_schema', 11, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpseo_schema_webpage', 'remove_datePublished_property_from_webpage', 11, 1 );

/**
 * Removes the DatePublished graph pieces from the schema collector.
 *
 * @param array  $pieces  The current graph pieces.
 * @param string $context The current context.
 *
 * @return array The remaining graph pieces.
 */
function remove_datePublished_from_schema( $pieces, $context ) {
    return \array_filter( $pieces, function( $piece ) {
        return ! $piece instanceof \Yoast\WP\SEO\Generators\Schema\datePublished;
    } );
}

/**
 * Removes the DatePublished property from the WebPage piece.
 *
 * @param array $data The WebPage's properties.
 *
 * @return array The modified WebPage properties.
 */
function remove_datePublished_property_from_webpage( $data ) {
    if (array_key_exists('datePublished', $data)) {
        unset($data['datePublished']);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: this also doesn't work, nice api and changes Yoast

Answer (score 0):

This works as per June 2023, regardless of all the bs in their documentation

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_schema_article', 'remove_article_dates' );
function remove_article_dates( $data ) {
    unset( $data["datePublished"] );
    unset( $data["dateModified"] );

    return $data;
}
```

**note**: you can still see some `datePublished` or `dateModified` inside the schema json in the DOM, but those are related to images or other media inside the post.
This got me stuck for a while because I was just testing by searching datePublished not paying attention to this detail.

Answer (score 0):

This code removes datePublish and dateModified from pages (webPage schema).

```
    add_filter('wpseo_schema_webpage', 'remove_date_fields_from_webpage');

/**
 * @param array $data The WebPage's properties.
 *
 * @return array The modified WebPage properties.
 */
function remove_date_fields_from_webpage($data) {
    if (isset($data['datePublished'])) {
        unset($data['datePublished']);
    }

    if (isset($data['dateModified'])) {
        unset($data['dateModified']);
    }

    return $data;
}
```